# How does one install an emulator onto the Playstation phone (Sony Xperia Play)?

Tags: applications, emulators

I got a Playstation phone (Sony Xperia Play) and would love to play old video games on it for free. I was hoping there was an emulator (maybe mame?) I could install on it. Is there some way I could do this?

EDIT: I'd like something that makes use of the playstation control buttons on my particular phone

Comment: For any particular system? Did you look in the Market? Searching just for "MAME" returns several relevant results: https://market.android.com/search?q=MAME&so=1&c=apps.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that I would need to jailbreak it. I guess coming from the world of iPhone to Android, my expectations don't align with reality.

Comment: Hmm, just took a look. Do you know if any of them can make use of the Xperia's playstation buttons? That's what I'm looking for in particular.

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I feel like at least a handful are able to use other hardware buttons (like on the original Droid's slide-out keyboard), but I couldn't really say for sure. I have an EVO, which lacks any hardware buttons at all, so it's never been something I could test/consider.

Comment: The Xperia PLay supposedly has an emulator built in already,Sony is offering some PS1 games on the market, there were PS1 emulators on the market but due to this they were removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are! Currently I found a Mame, Gameboy, N64, Snes, ScummVM (emulates classic adventure titles like Secret of Monkey Island, THE DIG, Day of the Tentacle, Grim Fandango and Broken Sword) and a Genesis emulator.

All of them use the PSX buttons but you need to configure all of them in the internal emulator configuration.

I have them all installed but I only tested the MAME, Sness and ScummVM emulator. I also have been told that some of these were removed from the market since they were paid apps that were copied from open source emulators. I have no idea about the legality of the use of emulators.

Since some of the APKs are not available via Market you'll need to install a file manager and allow the android system to install apps that are not from the market.

I really can't find the direct links to the emulators, but here it is their websites:

- [Gameboy](http://www.gameboid.com)
- [N64oid](http://code.google.com/p/n64oid/)
- [SNES A. D.](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bslapps.snes&hl=en)
- [ScummVM](http://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/Android/Guide)
- [Genplus-Droid (GENESIS)](http://code.google.com/p/genplus-droid/)
- [Tiger Emulator (MAME)](http://apps.tigerplay.info/)

*Btw:* The Tiger Emulator page says that it also emulates other platforms, I've only tried Marvel vs Capcom and Metal Slug.

Oh yeah, they also run great with zero lag but they'll usually suck your battery dry.

**Edit:** I tested all of them and everyone works like a charm, with the exception of the N64 emulator. Some games like Mario Kart 64 run OK and other like Pillotwings64 are unplayable.

**Double Edit:** I've been doing some research about PSX emulators and some close friends have recommended me FPse (Free Playstation Emulator) - it's supposed to be free but someone is selling it on the Droid Market.

I haven't got the chance to test it and I'll only get my PSX games after the weekend I believe that if someone does want to emulate PSX, it seems like a good way to start.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [PPSSPP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ppsspp.ppsspp), which is a PSP emulator. Although it's still in the beta stage it works fairly well.

Comment: Please add a link to the App :)

Answer (score 0):

There are huge number of consoles that can be emulated on android devices including gameboy, nintendo, myboy and some other similar consoles too.

The best by far is the PSP emulator for android called PPSSPP, it works best although might require good hardware configuration on your android device. Here is how to [play psp games on android](http://androiddelta.com/play-psp-games-android-device-including-lollipop-devices/) using [ppsspp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ppsspp.ppsspp)

Comment: Link answers are not [good answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), not everyone may be able to access the link you provided. The page may no longer be available. The site could be down permanently. Linking to a url as a source of the solution is fine, but you should [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/95399/edit) your answer and include the steps that answer the original question in your answer. Without the steps, your answer does not answer the question, you just tell them to go somewhere else.

Comment: @RyanConrad He gave a link to the app. If that link goes down, the answer will be useless however he describes it

Comment: @samsung, Yes, there is a link to the app. If the link doesn't provide anything extra, why is it included? Also there is already an answer from a year ago that links to the same app. If there is additional information needed, then it should be in this answer, not just a link to another site. Example, "might require good hardware configuration", an explanation of this, and what should be set, would be good information to include in the answer. An answer should not require the user to create more questions just to clarify the answer.